# Accessing >=2 collections from the same db connection using Mongo-lite results in error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to access more than a single mongo collection from the same db connection using mongo-lite. Here is a sample express app.

```
var express = require('express')   ;
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var mongolite = require('mongo-lite');

db = mongolite.connect("mongodb://localhost/fnard", ['col1','col2']);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    db.collection('col1').insert({hi:5},function(){});
    db.collection('col2').insert({hi:5},function(){});
    console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
    response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + '3000');
});
```

Here is the error I am getting on doing a GET on /:

```
Error: A Server or ReplSetServers instance cannot be shared across multiple Db instances
```

However if I use the following code the GET inserts the documents as expected

```
var express = require('express')   ;
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var mongolite = require('mongo-lite');

db = mongolite.connect("mongodb://localhost/fnard", ['col1']);
db2 = mongolite.connect("mongodb://localhost/fnard", ['col2']);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    db.collection('col1').insert({hi:5},function(){});
    db2.collection('col2').insert({hi:5},function(){});
    console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
    response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});
```

Do I need to really create a new connection for each collection I want to access?
The mongo-lite docs seem to suggest that this isn't the case - the .connect() option lets you specify which collections you want to use but it doesn't seem to work.

[mongo-lite docs link](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/mongo-lite/docs/index.html)

Comment: Haven't used mongo-light, but mongoose and native driver support querying 2 or more collections just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A race condition is giving you the error. The following works for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var mongolite = require('mongo-lite');

db = mongolite.connect("mongodb://localhost/fnard", ['col1','col2']);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    db.collection('col1').insert({hi:5},function(){
        db.collection('col2').insert({hi:5},function(){
            console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
            response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
        });
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + '3000');
});
```

You need to nest your callbacks. Or, you can use a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var express = require('express');
var async = require( 'async' );
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var mongolite = require('mongo-lite');

db = mongolite.connect("mongodb://localhost/fnard", ['col1','col2']);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    async.series( [

        // First insert
        function ( callback ) {
            db.collection('col1').insert({hi:5},callback);
        },

        // Second insert
        function ( callback ) {
            db.collection('col2').insert({hi:5},callback);
        }

    // Send response
    ], function ( error, results ) {
        console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
        response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
    } );
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + '3000');
});
```

Comment: You bet. Same problem.

Comment: How is this race condition arising? I have another set of very similar code where I am only doing 'finds' and yet am still getting the same error.

Comment: Probably the way the library is written? It can only query/update one collection at a time?

Comment: Try your code in `synchronous mode`. http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/mongo-lite/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to use the native mongo driver instead (where this issue isn't arising). I'll accept your hard work as the answer though.